# Windows tool or Google Chrome extension to select a rectangle from the screen or browser window?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome-extensions

I just realized I often want to select just a rectangle from the browser window which is not just a single image.

For instance sometimes I want to select just part of a composite image and other times I want to select a large part of the browser viewport but not the whole app.

Currently I have to either copy the image in the first case or do a `prt sc` in the second case, open The Gimp or similar, paste the image in, then crop it.

Either a Google Chrome extension that just works in the browser, or a Windows tool that works across the whole OS screen would be a good solution.

A perfect solution would even give me a popup menu that gives the choice of saving the selection as a temporary file or copying to the clipboard, maybe even uploading to some webservice and putting the resulting URL on the clipboard.

One use-case is that I'm often looking for the original or in-context source of a photo or image posted on the net and the image has often been composed with several smaller images. I'm only interested in where the pieces came from before the composition. Tineye and Google Image Search both work with either a URL or local file to upload.

Another use case is to upload bits of my screen which need to be cropped but not pixel-perfect to websites including Stack Exchange sites.

**Does anybody know of a Windows tool or a Chrome extension which has at least a few of these features?**

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/773545/capture-region-of-website-etc-to-clipboard-as-image/773568#773568

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/) allows you to instantly crop after creating a screenshot.

Comment: So far I like it - it implements a decent subset of the features I wanted (-:

Answer (score 1):

The built in Windows Snipping Tool, found in Accessories, does just this. It lets you select a part of the screen and saves it to a .png file.

Comment: I believe I looked for this tool once a year or so ago and found out it's not included with the crappy "Starter" edition of Windows 7 that netbooks come with )-:

Comment: @hippietrail http://www.mirekw.com/winfreeware/mwsnap.html