# Capture region of website/etc. to clipboard as image?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome-extensions

I often need to capture a fixed portion of my screen (typically in Chrome) to the clipboard, for posting as a background in a PowerPoint slide.

### Question

Where can I find an extension for Chrome or an app for Windows 7 that can accomplish the desired (below)?

### Desired

1. Select a region for storage in the clipboard.

### Undesired

But because I cannot do that, I need to:

1. Capture my screen via 3rd party software.
2. Save the captured region as a file.
3. Paste in the image.
4. Crop the image.
5. Clipboard the resulting image.

Comment: Windows snipping tool?

Comment: @BrianAdkins Yes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use extension from Chrome Web Store, like this one:

[**Awesome Screenshot: Capture & Annotate**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesome-screenshot-captur/alelhddbbhepgpmgidjdcjakblofbmce)

Using this tool, you can capture

- visible part of page
- selected area
- entire page
- local image
- desktop (premium feature)

If you need to take screenshot of other applications, you can use **Snipping Tool**.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Brian (see comments on OP).

### Built-in tool

Windows Snipping Tool comes with Windows 7 (and I believe everything from Vista on did).

### Usage

(A) Beginners:

1. Press "Start".
2. Type "Snipping Tool".
3. Press "Snipping Tool".
4. Highlight the region you wish to take into your clipboard.
   {Finished}

(B) Experts:

1. Press "Start".
2. Type "Snipping Tool".
3. Right-click its icon and press "Properties".
4. Under the "Shortcut Properties" tab.
5. Press into the "Shortcut Key" field.
6. Assign a CTRL + ALT keyboard combination (recommended: left-hand only, like CTRL + ALT + A).
7. Press "Okay".
8. Use the CTRL + ALT keyboard combination, anytime.
9. Highlight the region you wish to take into your clipboard.
   {Finished}